# Exception handling compile error: Exception; must be caught or declared to be thrown

Tags: java

Im not sure why I am getting this error and have a feeling im missing something obvious here. It occurs on the line: Verify.Validate(number); with the error: Program5.java:23: error: unreported exception Exception; must be caught or declared to be thrown. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

-Chris

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Program5 
{

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
      // The driver class should instantiate a Verify object with a range of 10 to 100.
      Verify Verify = new Verify(10, 100);

      //Prompt the user to input a number within the specified range.
      System.out.print("Input a number between 10-100: ");

      // Use a Scanner to read the user input as an int.
      Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in); 
      int number = input.nextInt();

      // Use Try/Catch to test number
      try 
      {
            Verify.Validate(number);
            System.out.println("Number entered: " + number);
      } 
      catch (NumberNegativeException ex) 
      {
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
      } 
      catch (NumberLowException ex) 
      {
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
      } 
      catch (NumberHighException ex) 
      {
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
      } 
    }    
}
```

Comment: The solution is in the error message

Comment: yes, either `catch(Exception)` or let the main method `throws Exception`

Comment: This must be a dupe about 1000 times over.

Comment: "error: unreported exception Exception; must be caught or declared to be thrown" means that somewhere in that method an exception of the class Exception may be thrown, very likely from the `Validate` method.  You must either have a `catch` statement for Exception, or add a `throws Exception` clause to your method header.  (If you look at the source for `Validate` there is probably a `throws Exception` clause there.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your code there are 3 types of exception your validate(int) method may throw :

1) NumberHighException

2) NumberLowException

3) NumberNegativeException

So the code for your *validate(int)* method may look like this :

```
public void validate(int number) throws NumberHighException, NumberLowException,
                                  NumberNegativeException {
   if(number > 100)
       throw new NumberHighException("Number is High");
   if(number < 10)
       throw new NumberLowException("Number is Low");
   if(number < 0)
       throw new NumberNegativeException("Number is Negative");
   else
       System.out.println("Your Entered Number is valid");
}
```

Now , while compiling your code, you are getting *Error* at:

```
catch (NumberNegativeException ex)  // Line no 23, where you are getting the error
{
    System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
}
```

And the error generated is :

```
 error: unreported exception Exception; must be caught or declared to be thrown
```

This indicates that the exception thrown is of higher(Super class) Type than as specified with the catch blocks.

So, somewhere in your *validate()* method , you're throwing an exception of type **Exception**. Just Correct it and you will be fine.

Answer (score -1):

Lets try using a more general catch:
try{
....
}catch(Exception e){
}
In this way you caught all the errors since every error extends the class Error